# Data grid view columns get duplicated when filling Data Grid View from Entity

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to C# and I have an issue on how to populate (fill) data grid view using entity from database. I have managed to managed to fetch data and put it in list in populate it to grid view **however** when I do that its not picking the columns on the grid view that i designed on designer its only duplicating the columns. Here is the end result if i fill data [image]

and Here is my code which is fetching data from database and populating the grid view

```
    IList<EmployeeEntity> emp = HibernateDAO.getRecords<EmployeeEntity>("from EmployeeEntity u");

    dataGridView1.DataSource = emp;
```

and the employee entity

```
 public class EmployeeEntity
    {

        public virtual int id_ { get; set; }
        public virtual String employeeno_ {get;set;}
        public virtual String lname_ { get; set; }
        public virtual String fname_ { get; set; }
        public virtual String sname_ { get; set; }
        public virtual String bdate_ { get; set; }
        public virtual String gender_ { get; set; }
        public virtual String address_ { get; set; }
        public virtual String contactno_ { get; set; }
       

    }
```

Comment: Your class EmployeeEntity and the database table EmployeeEntity do not have the same number of columns.  There is a EDMX file that creates a mapping between the database and the classes in c# that I think needs to be refreshed.

Comment: When you “manually” create the columns, are you setting each column’s `DataPropertyName` to the proper property name in the `EmployeeEntiy` class?

Comment: @JohnG no idea on how to do that. The code that I have populated is the only one I have

Comment: Example, in the designer, select the first column in the grid, look at its properties, there should be a property called `DataPropertyName`… set it to the string “id_” to match the `EmployeeEntity` property. Same for “Last Name”… `DataPropertyName` would be “lname_”… etc.